# Thinking sphinx conditions with if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I have such thinking sphinx search condition with or operator:

```
Oil.search "(@oiliness #{params[:oiloiliness].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')} | @oiliness #{params[:oiloiliness]}) | (@description #{params[:descr]})
```

but i must change it so, that i can use my or operator, but also add some if statement in condition: for example my params[:descr] is empty, so i didn't need to search via @description (also it will throw error's).

I need something like if params[:descr] then didn't use this part (@description #{params[:descr]}) . But what is the best way of doing this?

Maybe it is better and easier to use conditions "syntax" like:

```
Oil.search :conditions => {oiliness: "#{params[:oiloiliness].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')} | #{params[:oiloiliness]}",  params[:descr].present? ? description: "#{params[:descr]" : nil}
```

something like this...

also:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :oil, :with => :active_record do
  indexes :oiliness
  indexes :structure
  indexes :manufacturer
  indexes :capacity
  indexes :description
end
```

also i try:

```
@pre_oils = Oil.search :conditions => {oiliness: "#{params[:oiloiliness].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')} | #{params[:oiloiliness]}", description: "#{params[:oiloiliness].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')} | #{params[:oiloiliness]}", capacity: params[:oilsize], manufacturer: params[:oilbrand]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the OR logic in place, something like this should do the trick:

```
fields = ["@oiliness #{params[:oiloiliness].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')} | @oiliness #{params[:oiloiliness]}"]
fields << "@description #{params[:descr]}" if params[:descr].present?

Oil.search(
  fields.collect { |field| "(#{field})" }.join(' | ')
)
```